# universal jquery ajax call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

wondering is there any kind of global (universal) one function for calling ajax function..
for example i have lots of similar call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: some_url_address,
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){ 
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

and i would like to make it something like

```
callAjax('my_url', 'post', {some_data}, 'alert("success")');
```

and in javascript file:

```
function callAjax(url, type, data, successFunction, errorFunction, beforeFunction){
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
            beforeFunction;
        },
        success: function(){ 
           successFunction;
        }
        error: function(){ 
           errorFunction;
        }
    }); 
}
```

that in my page from where i'm calling that function it would return results from before, error, success, etc.. :)

Comment: the jquery function itself is already quite simple, isn't it? writing your own general function isn't that hard as you just demonstrated. It won't get more general. nonetheless there could be frameworks simplifying the process of testing.

Comment: Not sure what is your question/issue, but be aware you can return jqxhr object from method and then call any method of promise interface: `function callAjax(...){return $.ajax(...);};` and then  `callAjax(...).then(successFunction, errorFunction);`  http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Just install webpack by `npm install`.

And in the input field write `data-ajaxify='true'`

Also include the npm js and css file.

```
<input type='test' data-ajaxify='true' data-url='/someurl' data-method='post'>
```